# Octave problem :"OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long"

Tags: python, octave

I wrote this code:

```matlab
%case-2
 kp=3;
 ki=2*kp;
 Gc=kp+ki/s;
 delta=2.5;
G=[(6*s-10*delta)/(s^2+3*delta*s+100*delta)];
sys=feedback(Gc*G,1);

%state transition matrix
[num,den]=tfdata(sys)
disp('with PI controller')
[A2,B2,C2,D2]=tf2ss(num{1},den{1})

%Find the state transition matrix ?(t).
syms s t
exp_1= inv((s*eye(3)-A2))
Exp_At2=ilaplace(exp_1,s,t);
disp('required state transtion matrix is ')
pretty (Exp_At2)
```

However it gives me this message:

> ```
> error: Python exception: OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
>     occurred at line 2 of the Python code block:
>     f = inverse_laplace_transform(F, s, t)
> error: called from
>     pycall_sympy__ at line 178 column 7
>     ilaplace at line 171 column 5
>     TF at line 26 column 8
> ```

Comment: Your question is implicit. Please [edit] your post and make it explicit, so that people don't feel like they're guessing as to what you need. Read also [ask].

Comment: Also, `A2` is likely a 3x3 matrix. Instead of all that code to compute it, write `A2=[...]` (with the actual values you have computed). That keeps the code as short as possible to reproduce your problem, and makes it easier for us to help you.